# Why are changes in an object no longer reflected after reassignment?

Tags: javascript, reference, javascript-objects, variable-assignment

I think I could best explain my confusion with code:

```js
var options = {};

exports.options = options;
exports.options.a = "a";
console.log(exports.options, options);

exports.options = {};
console.log(options, exports.options);
```

The first output is:

```js
{ a: "a" } { a: "a" }
```

Great, it looks like anything done to `exports.options` will be done to `options`! But the second output is:

```js
{ a: "a" } {}
```

What happened? Why is `options` not also `{}`? What can I do to “empty” `exports.options` which also empties `options`?

---

The same goes with:

```js
options = {};
console.log(options, exports.options);
```

Which outputs:

```js
{} { a: "a" }
```

Comment: Because `options` still points to the original object. `exports.options = {};` makes a new object, it doesn't modify the old one or point any other variables to the new one.

Comment: Closely related: [Variable re-assignment of object reference leaves other object unaltered (no “transitive” assignment)](/q/41814414/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

When you do this,

```
exports.options = options;
```

you are assigning a *reference* of the object associated wtih `options` to `exports.options`.

When you change it again,

```
exports.options = {};
```

you are assigning a new reference to `exports.options` without changing `options`.

Comment: If I replace `exports.options = {};` with `options = {};`, I still get the same behavior.

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea Then you're changing what object `options` refers to without changing the object that `exports.options` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand by the following code

```
var options = {};  // Let's say Ref1
exports.options = options; // Ref1 passed to exports.options
exports.options.a = 'a'; // still Ref1 
console.log(exports.options, options); // So both will be updated
exports.options = {}; // New reference say Ref2, which has nothing to do with Ref1
console.log(options, exports.options); // Therefore changing Ref2 doesn't affect Ref1
```

When you are doing `exports.options = {};` the first reference is destroyed and a new reference gets stored, which is in no way connected to the first reference. So `options` which has a separate reference, which *still* represents `{a : 'a'}` does not get affected.

Comment: If I replace `exports.options = {};` with `options = {};`, I still get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with reference variables (which includes variables that point to objects), it's helpful to think of a variable as a *box* that holds a value.

You start off with one box called `options` that holds an empty object.  You also have a box called `exports`.  Inside the `exports` box, you put *another* box called `options`...that contains the same object that `options` contains (this is where the physical box analogy starts is strained, but just imagine that two boxes can contain the same physical thing).

The variable name is simply the name written on the box.  So now you have three boxes:

- Box `options` containing empty object X (I'm arbitrarily calling it X)
- Box `exports` containing...

  - Another box labeled `options` that also contains object X

When you do the assignment `exports.options = {}`, all you are doing is *putting something different in that box*, in this case, a new object Y.  So now you have:

Box `options` containing empty object X (I'm arbitrarily calling it X)
Box `exports` containing...
   Another box labeled `options` that contains object Y

So you can see that `options` and `exports.options` options point to different things, even though their names are the same.